# Get the largest image based on a thumbnail in a URL

Tags: media-library

I learned wordpress in just a few months ago and I am not that expert with this one.

I have the URL access of the thumbnail of an image. Now, I want to get the largest image based on the thumbnail image on the URL but I can't locate this largest image.

I checked the wordpress image sizes and saw that the largest image is 1024x1024. My image is:

www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017-04-sample-image-370x370.jpg

I tried to change the dimension to:

www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017-04-sample-image-1024x1024.jpg

But, it did not work as I expected. Also, I searched the image name in products and media gallery but can't find it.

Is there a way do it?